# RPi GPIO control lost (without any error) when running script from PHP

Tags: php, python, crash, gpio

I have been creating a little program that will allow me to control the GPIO pins through Python. This all went smoothly. The problem happens when I try calling this python script from PHP. It seems to loose functionality to control the GPIO pins, and crashes silently without any error.

The following files exist:

- RRR.py     -    The main file thats loosing perms
- configCreator.py       -         Generates a config.ini file that the
- RRR.py file makes use of

  - config.ini          -           The config that has been generated
  - install.py       -          Installs apache2 and php and generates a webpage that links to the RRR.py file.
  - index.php       -      A simple page with only a form
  - control.php          -           A file uses GET to retrieve variables and builds a command for execution.

When running an example command of `python3 RRR.py -c ON -r 5`, it properly takes control of the 5th devices mapped pins.

I can get the same command by placing the following URL -> `192.168.x.x/control.php?com=ON&dev=5`
A PHP echo shows me the `$command` var holds the following `python3 RRR.py -c ON -r 5`

I use PHP to execute this command using the following -> `$output = shell_exec($command);`
and then view the output by using -> `echo "<pre>$output</pre>"`

I get the following output:

```
Sending command (ON) to device (5)
Performing operation. This will take 1 second(s)...
Please wait...
```

This is when the GPIO pins are means to be controlled from the following lines in the RRR.py file:

```
 GPIO.setup(devPin, GPIO.OUT)
 GPIO.output(devPin, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(sleepTime)
 GPIO.output(devPin, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Where `devPin` is a GPIO pin number that has been worked out from the `config.ini`. Don't worry about this part, it works fine. The pin numbers are still correct when being ran from PHP. The GPIO commands simply don't work.

This leads me to believe that the problem lies fully with the very first line of the file, however, no error is generated. The first line being:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Maybe PHP's shell_exec doesn't have the correct perms to use the GPi.GPIO python module? Anyone know how I would fix this? I'll be grateful for any and all suggestions. I'd really like to get this project to work :)

---

tl;dr : Everything works FINE from the command line, but totally breaks when the exact same commands are called from PHP.

Comment: Can you please add the output from `ls -l /dev/gpiomem` and the result from `system('id');`? I thing I've got an idea

Comment: ls -l /dev/gpiomem gave this:
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 244, 0 Mar  4 04:54 /dev/gpiomem
                                              
And the result from system('id'); :
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Access GPIO pins without root. No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root) your python script will write to `/dev/gpiomem`.

This doesn't work, because the user that runs your python script (`www-data`) is not allowed to write to this device:

- To write there you need to be root or in the `gpio` group.
- The user `www-data` is neither `root` nor in the `gpio` group.

In order to access gpio ports, you need to put the `www-data` user in the correct group:

```
sudo usermod -aG gpio www-data
```

Don't forget to restart your http server (and `php-fpm` if applicable). You won't notice a difference otherwise.

Comment: Damn! Spot on! Hit the nail on the head. Thank you very much! I would have probably never got to that. Reloaded apache2 and now the GPIO pins respond to my web-inputs perfectly.